# Printing an array of nodes

Tags: c, avl-tree

Is it possible to print an array of nodes? I need to display the AVL tree as it is being built, but whenever I run this code, the program crashes. Any alternative ways around this?

```
     int k = 0;
    t = NULL;
    node* nodearray[32];
    for( j = 0; j < 33; j++)
    {
        printf ("Table %d \n", j+1);
        printf ("LineNum Left Data Right\n");
        t = Insert(j, a[j], t );

    for (k= 0 ; k < j ; k ++)
    {
         printf ("%5d %5d %5d %5d", nodearray[k]->num, nodearray[k]->left->data, nodearray[k]->data, nodearray[k]-> right ->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: it crashes because probably you are having some illegal memory access

Comment: Your question doesnt provide key details to answer it. Where are you exacly getting the crash ` ?

Comment: it crashes after the second iteration

Comment: With regards to memory access, I'm declaring space in the Insert function: T = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

Comment: use macros, they can provide safety
#define SIZE (32)

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

1. `nodearray` is uninitialized - the pointers in it have indeterminate values. Dereferencing them invokes undefined behavior.
2. `for( j = 0; j < 33; j++)` - but you declared `nodearray` to be 32 elements long. It's hard to tell without seeing the implementation of `Insert()`, but probably you also have an off-by-one error (you're reading/writing past the end of the array).